# Redirect subdomain to another domain with dns or htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, plesk

I'd like to redirect `subdomain.domain1.example` to `domain2.example` without changing the URL of subdomain.

Example:

`subdomain.domain1.example` = `domain2.example`

`subdomain.domain1.example/connexion` = `domain2.example/connexion`

Is it possible with DNS or `htaccess` redirection (not 301 or 302) ?

It's the same website with 2 URLs. By the way, I'm using Plesk to handle my server.

I know it appears like duplicate content to Google, but I don't care.

PS1: I can use rsync, but it's not really good solution

PS2: I tried symbolic link but Plesk doesn't like that

Comment: How is `subdomain.domain1.com` currently configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's the same website with 2 urls. ... I kwnow it appears like duplicate content to google"

So in that case it's not a "redirect" that you want - as that will change the hostname to `domain2.example`.

One way would be to:

1. Set a DNS `A` record for `subdomain.domain1.example` that points to the IP address of `domain2.example`.
2. In the `<VirtualHost>` container of `domain2.example` configure a `ServerAlias` so that the server will accept requests to `subdomain.domain1.example`. For example:

   ```
   ServerAlias subdomain.domain1.example
   ```

Comment: Yes that's right, not a redirect, sorry. Thank you for responding me, i'll try that way !

Comment: For nginx it's `server_name subdomain.domain1.example`

Comment: So, you're on Nginx, not Apache? It was just that you discussed `.htaccess` in your question - which is an Apache config file. (?)

Comment: I'm not an expert, i've two options for apache and nginx in plesk configuration, so i put ServerAlias and server_name in configuration fields.